# How to run flask and mongoengine with a remote host?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I am following this example here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/

My problem lies here:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGODB_DB"] = "my_tumble_log"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "KeepThisS3cr3t"

db = MongoEngine(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This assumes that the MONGODB_DB is "my_tumble_log" on my local machine and default port. What if my mongo database is on a remote machine with a different port? How would I modify the example to allow this?

I have tried adding a line before the MONGODB_DB app.config:

```
app.config['MONGODB_CONNSTRING'] = "mongodb://myremotehost:myport"
```

Though it has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following configuration settings are available:

```
MONGODB_DB
MONGODB_USERNAME
MONGODB_PASSWORD
MONGODB_HOST
MONGODB_PORT
```

Comment: Is there a link to this documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately theres only code - so I opened: https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/29